# How to launch ModelSim on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, modelsim

I'm trying to launch ModelSim on ubuntu but getting this error `./vsim: 183: exec: ./../linux/vsim: not found` when I launch `./vsim` in the terminal. I have already changed `mode=${MTI_VCO_MODE:-"32"}` in the vsim file. And I checked in the directory `./../linux/`, `vsim` is in.

Can someone help me please ?